# 'Swapping to Development environment' to see more error information is not displaying additional information

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an error that I am trying to dig in to but hitting a wall in terms of getting more information out of ASP.Net Core.

The default error page tells me:

`Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.`

I have set Development in `launchSettings.json' like so:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    },
...
```

And this breakpoint is hit when running the app:
[image: startup.cs]

And yet the only message I get is:
[image: error when running the app]

All of this is happening locally on my machine and when running via VS.

Edit 1:
Have noticed the error page URL is *AzureADB2C/Account/Error* (which makes sense as the error is produced after having gone back after logging in to Azure B2C)

Answer (score 1):

the error page that you are showing, is just a page in your project (Error.chhtml) that is simply showing a generic message with a request Id.

in order to see the Error page that is used internally by ASP you need to add the `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` middleware.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        // other code
    }

    // other code
}
```

Comment: Have added that and I get the same error page/informtion. Also edited answer to add some context around the error relating to Azure B2C.